# get one same result with doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, doctrine

i have in Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine 1.2 such query:

```
 $this->query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('News')
      ->createQuery('a')->leftJoin('Tag c')->where('c.tag_id = 2' )  ->execute();
```

This return for example:

```
| id_news | tag | title_news |
| 1       | 1   | title1     |
| 1       | 2   | title1     |
| 2       | 1   | title2     |
| 2       | 2   | title2     |
| 2       | 3   | title2     |
```

etc.

how can i make this:

```
| id_news | tag | title_news |
| 1       | xxxx| title1     |
| 2       | xxxx| title2     |
```

(only one (1 and title1) and (2 and title2))
i dont would like repeat data from table news (id_news, title_news). tag not necessarily return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the 'WITH' clause in your join statement.
should be something like `->leftJoin('Tag c WITH c.tag_id = 2')`

or group the results by the news id `->groupBy('id_news')`